# Understanding Xdebug memory delta increase

Tags: php, xdebug

I have the following line in my trace file:

```
0.5927  12212144    2780040.00  ->  require_once(E:\web\lib\nusoap\nusoap.php)  E:\web\some_path\file.php:28
```

I know that requiring this file will cost 2.7MB of memory. Is it normal that simply requiring the file will cost that much? What impacts the memory cost when requiring a file?

I have another 13 lines that are requires and that cost at least 350 000KB of memory each. I have two more lines that cost 1MB each. Again, is this sort of thing normal?

**Edit #1:**

I started to look into this due to a memory leak. We have a script that will have the memory usage spike but when it comes down, there will be an increase of 10MB+ (ish) of RAM.

At one point, when Apache reaches 450 000 MB used, we start getting out of memory errors like these:

```
PHP Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated x) (tried to allocate y bytes) in/path_to/file.php(1758) on line z
```

Comment: Please select an answer below that answers your question. I'd say youc can't get a better answer as by Derick who wrote XDebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is quite normal. The nusoap library is quite large, but internally in PHP it is stored as a blown up binary representation. You need to realize that the require itself isn't taking up the space, but rather the included file.

I don't quite understand where your ".00" at the end comes from though. I've just checked the code and it does not create a floating point number.

cheers,
Derick

Comment: I imported the trace file into Excel to filter out rows and it added the .00.

Answer (score 0):

> Again, is this sort of thing normal?

Yes, that is normal. If you want to understand the delta, look into the xdebug source-code it explains it fairly well. Also read the xdebug documentation first, IIRC the website tells you that you should not take these numbers for real (and it looks like in your question you do somehow).

Also take care that xdebug is not for production use. If you need production memory usage, you need other tools.

Comment: I'm trying to find a memory leak. I thought using this approach was the defacto way to proceed.

Comment: Xdebug can be used to track memory related problems, however I won't sware on the delta. You might use it to get an educated guess where your memory related problem is lying, but xdebug depends here on what PHP itself offers and for example PHP reserves some space for includes, the memory can be larger than the included file itself (memory reservation can be costly, so most often programs reserve more at once and then consume the buffer over time). About what sort of memory leak are you speaking?